# How to make this sidebar appear on the right instead of left?

Tags: html, css

How do I reposition the sidebar shown in this example: https://bootstrapstudio.io/tutorials/sidebar-navigation to be on the right instead of the left?

Thank you, any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change `left:` to `right:` in the `.sidebar` CSS.

Ie., change:

```css
.sidebar {
  [...]
  left: 0;
  [...]
}
```

to:

```css
.sidebar {
  [...]
  right: 0;
  [...]
}
```